# what's COPA? 2 questions bellow

Tags: meaning

It's a quote from *The Marvelous Mrs.Masel*

> A-See that guy over there in the gray suit? Marty Segal. Yesterday, he scored his first Copa gig. Big, big deal.
>
> B-He just spilled coffee on his suit. Does the Copa know about that?
>
> A-That may be his opening bit.

I have 2 questions:

1. What is a **COPA**? I checked the dic it says something like football games but still confused me.
2. What's the meaning of **opening bit**?

Comment: The definite article in "the Copa" gives you a hint that it is a proper noun.

Comment: Thanks! I checked... It's a vedio(Copacabana ) all dancing and singing... I'm still kinda miss because of this line: Does Copa know about that? Sounds like Copa is lively.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copacabana_(nightclub)

Comment: You have set a very difficult task for yourself, trying to understand this particular TV show.  Not only does it use a lot of specialized vocabulary and slang, but it is full of mid 20th century cultural references that many young people in the US today would not understand.

Comment: Thankyou  Tᴚoɯɐuo! You always help me with the questions, and YES this drama is quite unfriendly to foreigners but since it's also so interesting and hilarious, I wanna try to understand the culture behind it. Thank you again for the wiki link, I guess I have understood the meaning of COPA in this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "opening bit" is the first story or joke of a "stand-up" comedian's routine.  If the opening bit involved him spilling coffee on his suit, it would be a "slapstick" routine, one in which the comedian acts like a bumbling fool or stooge.